# When I am using agora_uikit package in flutter. it's show me complete black screen

Tags: flutter, dart, agora.io

[agora_uikit](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_uikit)

Show me this error in the console when I am open the chat screen

```
W/libc    (26879): Access denied finding property "net.dns1"
W/libc    (26879): Access denied finding property "net.dns2"
W/libc    (26879): Access denied finding property "net.dns3"
W/libc    (26879): Access denied finding property "net.dns4"
```

When I move one video chat to another chat I have to get another error message

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(17, request to join channel is rejected, null, null)
E/flutter (28102): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:607
E/flutter (28102): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:177
E/flutter (28102): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (28102): #2      SessionController.joinVideoChannel
package:agora_uikit/controllers/session_controller.dart:404
E/flutter (28102): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (28102): #3      AgoraClient.initialize
package:agora_uikit/src/agora_client.dart:69
E/flutter (28102): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (28102): #4      _LiveMatchScreenState.initAgora
package:timemarks/…/live_screens/live_match.dart:49
E/flutter (28102): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Show me this error when I am exit from the video call

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
A SessionController was used after being disposed.

Once you have called dispose() on a SessionController, it can no longer be used.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      ChangeNotifier._debugAssertNotDisposed.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/foundation/change_notifier.dart:114
#1      ChangeNotifier._debugAssertNotDisposed
package:flutter/…/foundation/change_notifier.dart:120
#2      ChangeNotifier.removeListener
package:flutter/…/foundation/change_notifier.dart:233
#3      _ValueListenableBuilderState.dispose
package:flutter/…/widgets/value_listenable_builder.dart:177
#4      StatefulElement.unmount
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4983
#5      _InactiveElements._unmount
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1926
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you enter the wrong APP ID and token combination. If you're using a project with secure mode make sure that you enter the APP ID and `tempToken` for the channel that you're trying to join. In case you're not using a project in testing mode then adding just the APP ID should be able to fix this.